# Aggregator pattern in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

Is it possible to implement the [aggregator pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html) in RabbitMQ?

I have `A` … `N` messages that I need to wait for/aggregate before sending off to another queue `X`.

So I'm thinking I will have some kind of **unique ID** that ensures that messages are routed **exclusively** to **the same consumer** and then wait for all the messages to arrive.

Is this possible in RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, it is possible.**

But this is not RabbitMQ specific. Understanding what to aggregate and how to do it is beyond the responsibility of the message broker.

You need to write a service to subscribe to the relevant messages and then publish the result back. In the context of RabbitMQ, you could use [routing keys](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html) to ensure the right consumer gets the messages, but that is not the only way.